# how to pass from string to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, object, split

I have the following code in javascript.

```
var abc = `<div class="hello" data-id="99" data-price="100" data-category="mal">
        <div class="hello-category">Hello word</div>
        <div class="hello-description"><h2>The best burger in town 12345615</h2></div>
        </div>`;
```

And i want to get the following result:

```
<div class="hello" data-id="99" data-price="100" data-category="mal">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
var abc = `<div class="hello" data-id="99" data-price="100" data-category="mal"><div class="hello-category">Hello word</div><div class="hello-description"><h2>The best burger in town 12345615</h2></div>`;
const parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(abc, "text/html");
parser.body.firstChild.innerHTML=''; //<-- remove innerhtml of the div
const result = parser.body.innerHTML; //<-- get result
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it into a DOM node and then perform DOM manipulation on it, like this

```js
const abc_string = `<div class="hello" data-id="99" data-price="100" data-category="mal">
        <div class="hello-category">Hello word</div>
        <div class="hello-description"><h2>The best burger in town 12345615</h2></div>
        </div>`;

//  convert string to DOM node
const abc_node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(abc_string, 'text/html').body.firstChild;

//  iterate over child nodes, removing them each time
Array.from( abc_node.childNodes ).forEach(thisChild => {
   abc_node.removeChild( thisChild );
});

//  what you have left
console.log(abc_node);
```